# Method not found while using <p:remoteCommand> button in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{searchAction.searchMasterId}: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /files/search.xhtml @186,176 action="#{searchAction.searchMasterId}": Method not found: com.action.SearchAction@1130c0a.searchMasterId()
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:85)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:334)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
```

I am getting the above error, Even I explicitly mention the method
I have added `<p:remoteCommand name="getMasterDetails" action="#{searchAction.searchMasterId}" />`

I have controller method as

```
public String getSearchMasterId() {
            //some code
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show the method in question? If you're absolutely positive that it has the right signature, then it most likely means that you're not running the code you think you're running. Clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart.

Comment: @BalusC added the method code. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on EL 2.2, there is an opportunity to call arbitrary methods with arbitrary parameters in your code, like:

```
public void doMyMethod() { ... };
public void doMyMethodWithParameters(String p1, int p2) { ... };
```

with JSF

```
#{bean.doMyMethod()}
#{bean.doMyMethodWithParameters(p1, p2)}
```

Note the parentheses at the end: `()`. If you don't write them, JSF will try to access property for the provided name, irrespective of whether it exists or not:

```
//note that 'private String doMyMethod' property is unnecessary
public String getDoMyMethod() { return ...; }
```

with JSF

```
#{bean.doMyMethod}
```

Note the absense of parentheses at the end and absense of `get` predicate within EL. `#{bean.doMyMethod}` will call `bean.getDoMyMethod()` and return the associated string.

In your case you need to access the method as: `#{searchAction.getSearchMasterId()}`.

Finally, it is worth noting that in some cases (action methods, action listener methods, AJAX behaviour methods, etc.) it is not necessary to include both the parentheses and the method parameters, as JSF expects a method with appropriate parameter and it will set it on its own.

Using this, it yields the same result without using the parentheses: `#{searchAction.getSearchMasterId}`.

It is also worth noting that you *might confuse* action method that performs business logic, or presets some value, with a method that gets a value to be displayed in a JSF component.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference between accessing controller method and managed bean property getter method.If I use `#{searchAction.searchMasterId}` for accessing controller method, why it is not working. It works perfectly fine with managed bean.